# spring boot ant matchers parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, web-development-server

I want to give permission to every of these URLs:

```
.antMatchers("/myPage?param1=tata*").hasRole("tata")
.antMatchers("/myPage?param1=toto*").hasRole("toto")
```

I have this two URLs:

```
http://localhost:3000/myPage?param1=tata&param2=0001
http://localhost:3000/myPage?param1=toto&param2=0001
```

If URL is typed and has "`tata`" as parameter i want to access only with the role "`tata`" and the same thing with "`toto`"

Comment: the problem is in the * i don't know if i put just one or two or something else ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RegexRequestMatcher` instead of `AntPathRequestMatcher`

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
         .regexMatchers("\/myPage\?param1=tata(&.*|$)"). hasRole('tata')
         .regexMatchers("\/myPage\?param1=toto(&.*|$)"). hasRole('toto')
```

`AntPathRequestMatcher` does **not** match the params，as you can read from the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.java#L192)

```
private String getRequestPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (this.urlPathHelper != null) {
            return this.urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication(request);
        }
        String url = request.getServletPath();

        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
        if (pathInfo != null) {
            url = StringUtils.hasLength(url) ? url + pathInfo : pathInfo;
        }

        return url;
    }
```

`RegexRequestMatcher` will get the request path and [params](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RegexRequestMatcher.java#L85).

```
public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (httpMethod != null && request.getMethod() != null
                && httpMethod != valueOf(request.getMethod())) {
            return false;
        }

        String url = request.getServletPath();
        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
        String query = request.getQueryString();

        if (pathInfo != null || query != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(url);

            if (pathInfo != null) {
                sb.append(pathInfo);
            }

            if (query != null) {
                sb.append('?').append(query);
            }
            url = sb.toString();
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Checking match of request : '" + url + "'; against '" + pattern
                    + "'");
        }

        return pattern.matcher(url).matches();
    }
```